# why data is undefined in post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m using react js app and I try to post data to my api , but I got undefined insert for one time .
instead of 'url' I have working url.

this is my post method's code:

```
senddata(){
    if(!this.formvalidation())
    {
    try{
    let resulte = fetch('url',{
     method:'post',
     mode:'no-cors',
     headers:{
         'Accept':'application/json',
         'Content-type': 'application/json'
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({
         ID:this.state.code,
         Blod:this.state.blod,
         Allergic:this.state.allergicdescription,
         Chronic:this.state.chronic_description
     })
    });
    alert("post");
    }catch(e){
      alert("not post")
    }
}
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Where do you run into an issue? within this function or outside of it?

Comment: Where do you get undefined? if you want to log `resulte` it's a `Promise` you have to await it. Do `async senddata` and then `await` fetch

Comment: thanks for replies , the error is just inside this function , the api working good , it send undefined data , I have added also async and awaiit and nothing changes

Comment: when I add async and await it say can't fetch data

Answer (score 0):

You said `mode:'no-cors'` so any attempt to do anything which requires permission from CORS will fail silently.

Setting `'Content-type': 'application/json'` requires permission from CORS.

Presumably, your server side code is not parsing the request body as JSON since the Content-Type header doesn't say it is JSON.

Since there is no parsed data, all the properties you want to read from the JSON will be undefined.

Don't use `mode:'no-cors'` if you want to POST JSON.

Comment: thanks for your info , I have tried deleting this , and it does not send anything and no error returned